# Resolver promesas desde distintas funciones

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas

Estoy haciendo una especie de *canal* de comunicaciones, que envía peticiones y recibe respuestas.

La función que envía una petición, quiero que devuelva una `Promise`, que será *resuelta* por la función de recepción (interna de la clase).

Y ahí me he atascado:

```
class IOChannel {
  constructor( channel ) {
    this.$channel = channel;
    this.$queue = { };

    channel.on( 'message', ( data ) => {
      if( 'error' in data ) {
        // Es una respuesta con un error. // <- ¿ ?
      } else if( 'result' in data ) {
        // Es una respuesta. // <- ¿ ?
    } );
  }

  $nextId( ) { ... }

  async sendRequest( params ) {
    this.$channel.send( {
      id: this.$nextId( ),
      params: params
    } );

    return new Promise( ); // <- ¿ ?
  }
}
```

Tanto las solicitudes salientes como las respuestas entrantes están relacionadas mediante el atributo `id` del mensaje. La idea era usar la variable `this.$queue` como punto de unión entre las solicitudes salientes y las respuestas entrantes, basándome en ese atributo `id`.

Pero **no se me ocurre** como relacionar la función *callback* de respuesta a un `message` con la `Promise` generada en la función `sendRequest( )`.

¿ Como tengo que modificar mi código para que la función `sendMessage( )` devuelva una promesa válida, que será *resuelta* o *rechazada* por mi función *callback* ?

#### Edito

La intención es invocar esa función `sendRequest( )` desde manejadores de rutas de `express`:

```
const express = require( 'express' );

const app = express( );
const ioChannel = new IOChannel( process );

app.post( '/login', body-parser, function( req, res ) {
  const view = await ioChannel.send( {
    login: req.body.userId,
    pass: req.body.pass
  } );

  res.status( view ? 200 : 401 ).end( );
}
```

Comment: Quieres que sendRequest devuelva una promesa para luego resolverla o rechazarla dentro del callback de onmessage?

Comment: @RicardoCuaresma Exacto. Estoy *muy mucho* verde con las promesas, **era** feliz con las antiguas *callbacks* :-(

Comment: Podrías mostrar a donde invocas a sendRequest?, las funciones async una vez las invocas devuelven una promesa, cuando el método async termina de ejecutarse.si no lanzas una excepcion, esa promesa se termina resolviendo, eso por el objeto Promise que devuelves en tu codigo actual, lo digo por si aun no lo has tenido en cuenta

Comment: See, igual cuando te vas acostumbrando a usarlas te vas dando cuenta que los callbacks te sacan bastantes canas xD

Comment: @RicardoCuaresma Editado con un caso de uso. Realmente aun no existe dicho caso, porque la clase `IOChannel` no está terminada. Un problemilla con promesas y tal :-)  Insisto en que **era** muy feliz con mis *callbacks*.

Comment: Si estoy entendiendo bien, quieres que la ejecución del método sendRequest termine cuando se haya procesadl el mensaje en el callback de `chanel.on`?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Exacto. El `this.$queue` es porque no se me ocurre como relacionar una cosa con otra; como todos los mensajes (petición o respuesta) tienen un `id`, había pensado en meter ahí el `id` del mensaje saliente y en el `on( )`, como la respuesta ha de tener el mismo `id`, relacionarlo con la promesa de alguna forma. Que igual es una tontería y no hace falta :-/

Comment: El problema estaría entonces en la implementación del propio `channel` que te está obligando a utilizar callbacks con promesas. En JavaScript moderno existen cosas como los async iterators que creo que podrían servir aquí. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for-await...of si pudieras mostrarnos la implementación de channel podría a ayudar.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Bueno, `channel` pertenece a la API de node y no lo puedo cambiar :-) Le echo un vistazo al enlace que indicas, gracias :-)

Comment: Cierto! Creo que entendí bien tú pregunta ahora. Creo que esta genial respuesta en el sitio de Inglés es lo que buscas. Muy parecido a la idea que tienes de guardar un id.https://stackoverflow.com/a/48444103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He creado una implementación sencilla con la ayuda de [**esta respuesta**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48444103/3866134) que creo que puede ser útil, aunque quizás esté lejos de ser algo usable en producción.

La idea es encapsular la lógica de la cola de `"resolvers"`, de forma que no se tenga que tratar fuera de la API pública `#on`.

Además tiene en cuenta que pueden existir diferentes `listeners` para cada evento y la promesa que devuelve el método `send` resuelve cuando todos los listeners terminen su tarea.

```js
class AbstractEventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    this.listeners = {};
  }
  
  on() {}
  
  off() {}
  
  send() {}
}

// EventEmitter
// Simula lo que ya hace "process" mediante process.send y process.on
class EventEmitter extends AbstractEventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  
  on(key, callback) {
    const listeners = this.listeners[key] || [];
    this.listeners[key] = [...listeners, callback];
  }
  
  off(key, callback) {
    if (!callback) {
      return delete this.listeners[key];
    }
    
    if (this.listeners[key]) {
      this.listeners[key] = this.listeners[key].filter(c => c !== callback);
    } 
  }
  
  send(key, ...args) {
    for (const callback of (this.listeners[key] || [])) {
      setTimeout(callback.bind(null, ...args), 0);
    }
  }
}

// AsyncEventEmitter
class AsyncEventEmitter extends AbstractEventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.nextId = 0;
    this.queue = new Map;
  }
  
  on(key, callback) {
    const callbackWrapper = (nextId, ...args) => {
      const task = this.getTask(nextId);
            
      if (!task) {
        return;
      }
      
      const { resolve, reject } = task;
      
      try {
        const result = callback(...args);

        resolve(result);
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    };
    
    const listeners = this.listeners[key] || [];
    this.listeners[key] = [...listeners, { callback, callbackWrapper }];
  }
  
  off(key, callback) {
    if (!callback) {
      return delete this.listeners[key];
    }
    
    if (this.listeners[key]) {
      this.listeners[key] = this.listeners[key].filter(({ callback: c }) => c !== callback);
    }  
  }
  
  
  getTask(nextId) {
    const task = this.queue.get(nextId);
    this.queue.delete(nextId);
    return task;
  }
  
  send(key, ...args) {
    const taskIds = [];
    
    for (const { callbackWrapper } of (this.listeners[key] || [])) {
      const taskId = this.nextId++;
      setTimeout(callbackWrapper.bind(null, taskId, ...args), 0);
      taskIds.push(taskId);
    }
    
    if (!taskIds.length) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
    
    return this.waitForTasks(taskIds);
  }
  
  waitForTasks(taskIds) {
    return Promise.all(taskIds.map(this.getTaskPromise.bind(this)));
  }
  
  getTaskPromise(nextId) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.queue.set(nextId, { resolve, reject }));
  }
}

// Testing

const process = new AsyncEventEmitter();
const key = Symbol('my-event');
const keyError = Symbol('my-error-event');

process.on(key, () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    // Do nothing
  }
  
  console.log('End for loop');
  return 1;
});

process.on(key, () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    // Do nothing
  }
  
  console.log('End 2nd for loop');
  return 2;
});


const onError = () => {
  throw new Error('Lo siento, me he equivocado, no volverá a pasar :/');
};

process.on(keyError, onError);
process.on(keyError, (...args) => 'Este callback será ejecutado, pero no se ejecutará el método #then de la promise que devuelve #send');

//process.off(keyError, onError);

process
  .send(key, 'Hello', 'World')
  .then((...args) => console.log('Processed', ...args));

process
  .send(keyError, 'Hello', 'World')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);

console.log('Waiting for process...');
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que necesitas es esto:

```js
class IOChannel {
  constructor( channel ) {
    this.$channel = channel;
    this.$queue = { };
    
  }

  $nextId( ) { ... }

  async sendRequest( params ) {
    this.$channel.send( {
      id: this.$nextId( ),
      params: params
    } );

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.$channel.on( 'message', ( data ) => {
      if( 'error' in data ) {
        // Es una respuesta con un error. // <- ¿ ?
        reject(data.error);
      } else if( 'result' in data ) {
        // Es una respuesta. // <- ¿ ?
        resolve(data.result);
    } );
    });
  }
}
```